# TypeError: list.push is not a function when pushing to localStorage

Tags: javascript

I am receiving a error when trying to take a user input (todo) and push it to the local storage as a value onto a key. The key is coming from the taskLists.value which is a HTML select form.

So let's say the list 1 is selected. And the user enters "Get groceries", and "Clean car". This should pass into the localstorage as a value, however it is providing me TypeError: list.push is not a function when pushing to localStorage.

From what i've read it is an issue with the parsing or stringify. However I am very confused despite reading on the issue which part it is exactly.

```
const taskLists = document.getElementById('task-lists');

function saveLocalTodo(todo) {
  let list;
  if (localStorage.getItem(taskLists.value) === null) {
    list = [];
  } else {
    list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(taskLists.value));
  }
  list.push(todo);
  localStorage.setItem(taskLists.value, JSON.stringify(list));
}
```

```
      <section class="side-bar grid1">
        <div class="select">
          <h3>Filter</h3>
          <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>
            <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
          </select>
          <h3>Saved Lists</h3>
          <form class="new-list-form">
            <button class="new-list-button form-button" type="submit">
              <i class="las la-plus-square"></i>
            </button>
            <input type="text" class="list-input" placeholder="Add list name" />
          </form>
          <select id="task-lists" name="lists" class="task-lists">
            <option>Select a list</option>
          </select>
          <button class="delete-button form-button">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </section>
```

```
<section class="main-content grid2">
        <form class="add-task-form">
          <button class="todo-button form-button" type="submit">
            <i class="las la-plus-square"></i>
          </button>
          <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="Add task" />
        </form>
        <div class="todo-container">
          <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
        </div>
      </section>
```

```
const listInput = document.querySelector('.list-input');

// Creates option in UI
function createNewList(event) {
  // Prevent form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();

  // Creates option element
  const newList = document.createElement('option');
  newList.innerText = listInput.value;
  taskLists.appendChild(newList);
  // Saves to local storage using form input
  saveLocalList(listInput.value);

  // Clear Todo Input Value
  listInput.value = '';
}

// Saves list to local storage
function saveLocalList(list) {
  localStorage.setItem(list, []);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML code as well :)

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe sorry about that, added it to the main post!

Comment: I just checked your code and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for checking. So that means that my function that creates a user list is the problem. I believe its is not making an empty array so that the taskLists function can be used. Ive added it to the main post.

Comment: Can you post that function as well?

Comment: Added to the main post with the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function: `saveLocalList(list)` saves the list name to localStorage without stringifying it. I think that causes the issue. Please try the below code:

```
// Saves list to local storage
function saveLocalList(list) {
  localStorage.setItem(list, JSON.stringify([]));
}
```